# How to save null data with Api-Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony-validator

With Symfony 5.1 and Api Platform, I am unable to effectively handle saving `NULL` data.

*Examples for this simple entity :*

```php
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    public $content;
}
```

*Example 1 (`POST` request) :*

```
{
  "name": "",
  "content": ""
}
```

**I agree, this is the good return (ConstraintViolationList)** :

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
  ...
  "violations": [
    {
      "propertyPath": "name",
      "message": "This value should not be blank."
    }
  ]
}
```

*Example 2 (`POST` request) :*

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "content": ""
}
```

The registration in the database is going well. In database, for `content` value, I have `""`. **But I want to save `NULL`**.

So I understand that Api Platform does not know how to transform empty data (`""`) to `NULL` data, as Symfony would after submitting an empty form.

So I try *Example 1* again, but with `NULL` data, to make sure the `Asserts` still work.

```
{
  "name": null,
  "content": null
}
```

**It doesn't work, I don't have a `ConstraintViolationList` error :**

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/Error",
  ...
  "hydra:description": "The type of the "name" attribute must be "string", "NULL" given.",
}
```

So how do I handle the null data so that if it's empty and mandatory I have an error list (`ConstraintViolationList`), but if it's optional then the data registers as `NULL` and no `""` ?

It would be a shame and very very very tedious to have to manage the sending of data differently depending on whether they are mandatory or not (sometimes send `""` and sometimes `NULL`).

Comment: Did you try `@Assert\NotBlank(allowNull=true)` ? Also: as pointed out by rugolinifr in his answer: you must allow the properties to be `null` as well, so make sure you getters/setters support that. The fact it says "constraint violation" means that the current issue you're asking about is with your `@Assert` constraints.

Comment: P.s - `NotBlank` validator means for a string property that the value may not be `''`. When you send `"name": null` without `allowNull=true`, a not-empty string is required, hence your constraint violation. _With_ `allowNull=true` it means the value may be `null` or must contain string characters (but still may not be `''` (empty)).

Answer (score 0):

Declare your property nullable:

```php
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var null|string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $name; // php < 7.4 style

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    public ?string $content;  // php >= 7.4 style
}
```